# Is possible to change the summary of EditTextPreference dynamically in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I set up a preferenceScreen to edit the settings in my application. I would like to insert an EditTextPreference that contains a Title like "set your name" and a summary containing the name entered.

Is that possible? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, here is a short example:

```
EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("the_pref_key");
etp.setSummary("New summary");
```

This requires that you display your preferences either from a `PreferenceActivity` or from a `PreferenceFragment`, since `findPreference()` is a method of these classes. You most likely do that already.

To change the summary every time the user changes the actual preference, use a [`OnPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) and check if the relevant key changed in the callback.
After it has changed, just edit the summary like above.